# Selecting element in a collection of buttons by text

Tags: c#, silverlight, automation, webaii

I am trying to loop through a collection of button objects in a SilverLight web page (there are 175 button objects) to find a button that has the text value = 'Airport". But I do not know how to get to the text property using WebAii (C#). Please could somebody help. Below is the code I have put together. The '????' parts are were I am stuck. Also, I am unsure of how to actually double click the element when I have found the one I am looking for, so if you could here here to it would be most appreciated.

```
var buttons2 =_silverlightApp.Find.AllByType<TextBlock>();         
for (int i = 0; i < buttons2.Count+ 1; i++)          
{

     if(buttons2.??????.text = "Airport")
     {
                 int elementNum = i;
                 ??????.LeftDoubleClick;
     }      

}
```

Comment: You are trying to find a certain button... is there a reason you are not using [AutomationIds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationproperties.automationid%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: Hi. Sorry Im unfamiliar with AutomationIds. Is this related to WebAii?

Comment: Actually Im not trying to find a a button, I am actually trying to find an element in a tree view with a a text value = 'Airport'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the `Buttons` you are displaying are created dynamically but in case it is an ordinary `Button`, declared somewhere in your xaml I recommend using `AutomationIds`.

```
<Button
    Content="Woohoo Airport! OMG!"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="AirportButton"/>
```

the WebAii class `VisualFind` offers

```
public FrameworkElement ByAutomationId(string id)
```

and you can call it on the (WebAii-)SilverlightApp or on a (WebAii-)FrameworkElement

```
SilverlightApp.Find.ByAutomationId("AirportButton");
FrameworkElement.Find.ByAutomationId("AirportButton");
```

Comment: Hi Martin. Thanks for the information. I didnt actually write the SilverLight App. I am just a poor misguided tester. but i have had a word with one of the SilverLight developers and he has told me that they dont have the 'AutomationProperties.AutomationId' property in the their Xaml. Also, most of the objects on the web site are dynamically generated, so Im thinking using 'ByAutomationId' wouldnt be the best approach for getting at specific elements. Any other advice would be much appreciated :-).

Answer (score 0):

I work for Telerik in the Test Studio and Webaii support team. I will endeavor to help you with this problem.

Let Webaii do the iterating and finding for you like this:

Button btn = _silverlightApp.Find.ByExpression(new XamlFindExpression("XamlTag=textblock","TextContent=Airport")).Parent().As();

I hope this helps.

Cody

Comment: Hi I am getting the following Error when i try to use this code, please can you help:- "The type argument for method 'ArtOfTest.WebAii.Silverlight.FrameworkElement.As<T>()' can not be inferred from the usage. try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: Sorry about that. StackExchange is removing critical parts of the code:

Button btn = _silverlightApp.Find.ByExpression(new XamlFindExpression("XamlTag=textblock","TextContent=Airport")).Parent< Button>().As< Button>();

Remove the spaces between < and Button.